# Can I Change display property in Javascript by getting variable from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, display

I have been trying to change display property in Javascript by getting a variable from PHP. I could send a variable to PHP with Ajax but I coudnt do it same vica versa. Basicly, I am making a login page by using PHP and this login form is in my index page. So each time when I login, the form to login will stil exist there. I dont want it. Is it possible (Somehow it should be as it is already done by some websites, I know) to hide that login form and display any user related information (for example user's profile picture)?
Here is what I have done untill now ;

```css
.tablelogin{
  background: #044559;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(342deg, #08384B, #03617C);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(342deg, #08384B, #03617C);
  background: linear-gradient(72deg, #08384B, #03617C);
 border-top-left-radius: 11%;
 border-top-right-radius: 11%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5%;
 display: none;
}

.loginbuttons{
 border-radius: 39%;
 border-bottom-color: rgba(17,101,255);
 color: rgba(0,0,64);
 background-size: 255px;
 box-shadow:20px 30px 50px 5px,rgba(9,54,64);
 border-top-color: rgba(14,77,191);
 background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(5,25,64),rgba(11,52,129), rgba(16,91,235));
 width: 55px;
 font-size: 11px;
}
.loginbuttons:hover{
 border-top-color: rgba(17,101,255);
 border-bottom-color: rgba(14,77,191);
}
.loginbuttons:active{
 border-left-color: rgba(5,45,64);
 border-right-color: rgba(5,83,127);
}
.textboxes{
 height: 11px;
 width: 55px;
 background-color: rgba(20,127,120);
 border-radius:11%;
 font-size: 11px;
 color: rgba(0,0,64);
}
.textboxes:focus{
 border-radius: 5%;
 width: 91px;
 height: 16px;
 box-shadow: rgba(5,11,91);
}
.textboxes:active{
 border-radius: 5%;
 width: 59px;
}
::placeholder{
 color:  rgba(5,5,91);
}
```

```html
<form  method="post" action="loginRegister.php">
  <table class="tablelogin" id="loginTables" name="loginTable">
   <tr style="display: inline">
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="textboxes" name="username">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="textboxes" name="password">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="display: block">
    <td>
     <input type="radio" name="logins" value="signIn"   onClick="SignIn()" placeholder="Sign in"><label style="font-size: 11px; color: #1295D5">Login</label>
    
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="radio" name="logins" value="register" onClick="Register()"><label style="font-size: 11px; color: #1295D5">Register</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="values" style="display: none;">
    <td>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="textboxes">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="textboxes">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="values2" style="display: none;">
    <td>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Country" class="textboxes">
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Birth-Date" class="textboxes">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td style="display: inline-block;">
     <input type="submit" value="Login" class="loginbuttons" id="submits" name="submits" onClick="login()">
     <input type="button" value="0" style="display: none;" name="logins" id="logins">
    </td>
    <td style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 9.12%">
     <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="loginbuttons">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

```
 <!-- php codes inside my index file -->
<?php
        session_start();
        include("connection.php");



        $sql = "SELECT userState FROM users WHERE userID = '$_SESSION[userID]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $userState=0;
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if($result)
        {
            $userState=$row["userState"]; //gets the login state. It is set to 0 when user logouts
        }
        if($userState==1) // if login state is 1 then it means user is logged in. So it must hide login form and display user related informations
        {
            echo "<script> window.alert('sfyhsjj');</script>"; //prints that random text
            echo ' <script> document.getElementById("logoupper").style.display="none";</script>' // It doesnt hide that
            echo "<script> window.alert('sfyhsjj');</script>"; // prints that random text

        }
    ?>//End of the code
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap your login form with php checking if userState isn't 1?
`<?php if ($userState!=1) { ?> YOUR_HTML_LOGIN_HERE <?php } ?>`

It should default to 0 and we could check for 0, but if your userState ever returns another number, say -1, or 2 for an error we'd still want to show the form.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can simply hide the form when the ajax returns success (and login succeeds) using ```$('#loginTables').css('display','none');```.

Comment: You might also have a div to display the user info returned by the ajax call, and populate it, the display it on the ajax return.

Comment: Hi firstly thanks for the comments. But , @bigbitecode Those codes are just a little part of the whole site. So I cannot do like this because its position will mess up.

Comment: @Sloan Thrasher  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submits").on("click", function(){
  var buttonState = $("#loginTables").serialize();
  
  $.ajax({
   url:'loginRegister.php',
   type:'POST',
   data:buttonState, 
   success:function(e){
    $("div").html("").html(e);
   }
  });
  
 });
}); I didnt understand at all what you mean. This is how I send varriables to PHP. It redirects me to login.php page checks login data and redirect back to index.php. So I think I need to make something like page loader to load only needed parts of the site for each time index page reloads.

Comment: I think you are confusing ajax with submitting a form. With ajax, there shouldn't be anything like a redirect. If the user's page is being refreshed from the server, then the ajax stuff should be removed, and just submit the form to a php script. Then that script would either display the results page, or redirect to another page.

Comment: BTW, edit your question rather than putting code in a comment. Way to hard to read there.

Answer (score 0):

Your script isn't hiding the elements because the login form doesn't have the id="logoupper".

Keep what you have, wrap the <form> in:

```
 <div id="loginform">
    <form  method="post" action="loginRegister.php">
    ... 
    </form>
 </div>
```

Then change

```
echo ' <script> document.getElementById("logoupper").style.display="none";</script>'; // It doesnt hide that
```

To

```
echo ' <script> document.getElementById("loginform").style.display="none";</script>';
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It doesnt matter. I just didnt write all the codes of the site here. There is a thing called "logoupper" but it doesnt hide it too.